# Eclipse for Java - run block of code like C++ #ifdef DEBUG

Tags: java, c++, eclipse, debugging, preprocessor

I wonder is it possible in Eclipse for Java (or rather in Java itself)  to run a block of code only in debug mode? Just like in C++:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
  // something to do
#else
  // something else to do
#endif
```

I know there is no preprocessor in Java, but maybe there is some workaround?

Comment: Java does not have conditional compilation. See answer from @MrPromethee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to approach this is to use a `public static final boolean` as a debug flag, import it when needed, and put your debug code in `if` blocks.

```
public static final boolean DEBUG = true;

import ClassName.DEBUG;

if (DEBUG) {
    doDebugThings();
}
```

Comment: But then I have to change something in code everytime when I want to debug. I thought rather about some Debug configuration...->Arguments value in Eclipse.

Comment: You only need to have one configuration class in which you change the value.

Comment: I just figured out an option. Debug confiiguration...->Environment gives to us a chance to set env vars. Then it would be possible to check such variable in app and even run it in debug-like mode. I have to check it...

Comment: You have a flag in vm argument say myproject.DEBUG that you pass as argument to your program and in your startup code you initialize DEBUG using System.getProperty("myproject.DEBUG").equals("true") or Boolean.getProperty("myproject.DEBUG").

Comment: @Satish Is it possible to read args[] via getProperty()? Anyway if you think about setting env arguments - I agree. Small disadvantage is Eclipse Run/Debug will always launch debug block. But I can live with it.

Comment: @rainbow if you like pass it as one of the argument you can do I think like -Dmyproject.DEBUG=true

Comment: @MrPromethee Small correction: you've forgot about "static" after "import".

Answer (score 0):

there is no java way to do this, see [Determine if a java application is in debug mode in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109019/determine-if-a-java-application-is-in-debug-mode-in-eclipse)

**there is this workaround:** 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43149241/5581745 that u could adapt to ur needs...

basic idea:

1. use a conditional break point, e.g. a class loader break point on ur startup class
2. write the condition like so `MyDebug.setDebugModeOn()`;

   - in this method goes ur debug init code, e.g. where ur set a `static public boolean DEBUG_MODE_IS_ON` var.
   - always return false from this, so the break point never causes a stop